# Use factors to plot dates out of sequence

Tags: r, plotly, lubridate, factors

I am trying to plot months and days that cross over different years, but not  display the year. I can use factors to force the dates to be out of order. If i have a single year of data this code works. but for multiple years i am running into trouble duplicating leap year, and also getting the plot to work.

Error: Column `x` must be length 1 or 730, not 365

I would like to use the factors to plot the years seasonaly one over the other for each "%m-%d".

Thank you.

```
dates <- format(seq(from = as.Date("2016-12-01"), to = as.Date("2018-11-30"),
                             by = "days"), format = "%m-%d")

values = c(rnorm(length(dates)/2, 8, 1.5), rnorm(length(dates)/2, 16, 2))

fDates <- factor(dates, dates)

plot_ly(x = ~fDates, y = ~values, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")
```

EDIT: This is the desired range for the x-axis. I use the factor to force the levels to conform to this order. I just need to be able to plot multiple years %m-%d against these x axis coordinates.

[1] 12-01 12-02 12-03 12-04 12-05 12-06 12-07 12-08 12-09 12-10 12-11 12-12 12-13 12-14 12-15 12-16 12-17 12-18 12-19 12-20 12-21
 [22] 12-22 12-23 12-24 12-25 12-26 12-27 12-28 12-29 12-30 12-31 01-01 01-02 01-03 01-04 01-05 01-06 01-07 01-08 01-09 01-10 01-11
 [43] 01-12 01-13 01-14 01-15 01-16 01-17 01-18 01-19 01-20 01-21 01-22 01-23 01-24 01-25 01-26 01-27 01-28 01-29 01-30 01-31 02-01
 [64] 02-02 02-03 02-04 02-05 02-06 02-07 02-08 02-09 02-10 02-11 02-12 02-13 02-14 02-15 02-16 02-17 02-18 02-19 02-20 02-21 02-22
 [85] 02-23 02-24 02-25 02-26 02-27 02-28 03-01 03-02 03-03 03-04 03-05 03-06 03-07 03-08 03-09 03-10 03-11 03-12 03-13 03-14 03-15
[106] 03-16 03-17 03-18 03-19 03-20 03-21 03-22 03-23 03-24 03-25 03-26 03-27 03-28 03-29 03-30 03-31 04-01 04-02 04-03 04-04 04-05
[127] 04-06 04-07 04-08 04-09 04-10 04-11 04-12 04-13 04-14 04-15 04-16 04-17 04-18 04-19 04-20 04-21 04-22 04-23 04-24 04-25 04-26
[148] 04-27 04-28 04-29 04-30 05-01 05-02 05-03 05-04 05-05 05-06 05-07 05-08 05-09 05-10 05-11 05-12 05-13 05-14 05-15 05-16 05-17
[169] 05-18 05-19 05-20 05-21 05-22 05-23 05-24 05-25 05-26 05-27 05-28 05-29 05-30 05-31 06-01 06-02 06-03 06-04 06-05 06-06 06-07
[190] 06-08 06-09 06-10 06-11 06-12 06-13 06-14 06-15 06-16 06-17 06-18 06-19 06-20 06-21 06-22 06-23 06-24 06-25 06-26 06-27 06-28
[211] 06-29 06-30 07-01 07-02 07-03 07-04 07-05 07-06 07-07 07-08 07-09 07-10 07-11 07-12 07-13 07-14 07-15 07-16 07-17 07-18 07-19
[232] 07-20 07-21 07-22 07-23 07-24 07-25 07-26 07-27 07-28 07-29 07-30 07-31 08-01 08-02 08-03 08-04 08-05 08-06 08-07 08-08 08-09
[253] 08-10 08-11 08-12 08-13 08-14 08-15 08-16 08-17 08-18 08-19 08-20 08-21 08-22 08-23 08-24 08-25 08-26 08-27 08-28 08-29 08-30
[274] 08-31 09-01 09-02 09-03 09-04 09-05 09-06 09-07 09-08 09-09 09-10 09-11 09-12 09-13 09-14 09-15 09-16 09-17 09-18 09-19 09-20
[295] 09-21 09-22 09-23 09-24 09-25 09-26 09-27 09-28 09-29 09-30 10-01 10-02 10-03 10-04 10-05 10-06 10-07 10-08 10-09 10-10 10-11
[316] 10-12 10-13 10-14 10-15 10-16 10-17 10-18 10-19 10-20 10-21 10-22 10-23 10-24 10-25 10-26 10-27 10-28 10-29 10-30 10-31 11-01
[337] 11-02 11-03 11-04 11-05 11-06 11-07 11-08 11-09 11-10 11-11 11-12 11-13 11-14 11-15 11-16 11-17 11-18 11-19 11-20 11-21 11-22
[358] 11-23 11-24 11-25 11-26 11-27 11-28 11-29 11-30
365 Levels: 12-01 12-02 12-03 12-04 12-05 12-06 12-07 12-08 12-09 12-10 12-11 12-12 12-13 12-14 12-15 12-16 12-17 12-18 ... 11-30

> 